# Why can we assign a struct pointer to an interface variable even though the struct pointer does not implement the interface?

Tags: go, types, interface, semantics

I present two programs below: program 1 and program 2.

I expect program 1 to fail to compile and it indeed fails to compile. So that's good.

I expect program 2 to fail to compile but it succeeds! This question is about why program 2 succeeds.

#### Program 1

https://play.golang.org/p/qX9nY8VLlx0

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X float64
    Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    
    a = Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(a.Abs())
}
```

This fails to compile with this error:

```
./prog.go:24:4: cannot use Vertex literal (type Vertex) as type Abser in assignment:
Vertex does not implement Abser (Abs method has pointer receiver)
```

I was expecting this error because `*Vertex` implements `Abser` but `Vertex` does not, so we cannot assign a `Vertex` object to an `Abser` variable.

#### Program 2

https://play.golang.org/p/4bIs-fHGhYm

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X float64
    Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    
    a = &Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(a.Abs())
}
```

This compiles successfully. The output of the program is:

```
5
```

Why did this succeed? Here, `Vertex` implements `Abser` but `*Vertex` does not implement `Abser`. How am I then able to assign a value of type `*Vertex` to `Abser`?

What are the language semantic rules I need to understand to know why this succeeds?

Comment: The method set for a pointer includes all methods for the value receiver.   The method set for a value does not include the methods for the pointer receiver.  See [Method Sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) in the specification.

Comment: @MuffinTop My example at https://play.golang.org/p/Kj5g6yJwI9s shows that while a method set of pointer type `*T` includes methods with receiver type `*T` or `T` (which is what you said). But I see that the same example also shows that a method set of a value type `T`  also includes methods with receiver type `*T` or `T` because both `v.AbsV()` and `v.AbsP()` succeed. Am I misinterpreting the results?

Comment: That is a different property. In the case of an addressable value, if the method needs a pointer receiver, the call is automatically changed to `(&x).m()`. See [calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) for details.

Comment: See rule #3 in [selector expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors).  There are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+abser) and answers on these topics.

Comment: "Am I misinterpreting the results?" Yes. This is even covered halfway through the Tour of Go (https://tour.golang.org/methods/6) which is worth working through as it explains this types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

The [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) requirements spell out what is needed in the case of interfaces:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
> T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> ...
> T is an interface type and x implements T.
> ...

To determine the rules of "x implements T", we turn to the concept of [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
> interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
> consists of all methods declared with receiver type T.

At first glance, this means that the method set of `Vertex` in your first example is empty, and the method set of `*Vertex` in your second example is also empty.

However, the spec goes on to specify:

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all
> methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the
> method set of T).

This means that the **method set of `*Vertex` automatically includes the method set of `Vertex`, but not the other way around**.

This does not help in your first example, but in the second example the method set of `Vertex` does include `Abs() float64`. Since this is all that is required to implement the `Abser` interface, `*Vertex` is deemed to implement `Abser`.